# how to get git parent branch name by given a SHA1

Tags: git

As title, ex: a merged commit 'M'
Can i get the two parent's branch name by `'M'`?
it is useful to understand that 'M' is come from `master` and `debug` branch.

```
A->B->C->M->E(master)
 \>X->Y/     (debug)
```

Thanks
Peter

Comment: Do you want to run some command for M and get master & debug as the result?

Answer (score 2):

Is this is what you are looking for?

```
git branch --contains=abcd
```

Comment: sorry, in the case above, i want to get the branch name of  `C1` and `Y`.

Comment: You can get list of branches that contains commits C and Y. Will it satisfy you?